# How to change the OS file manager path when uploading a photo to a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create a script that uploads photos to instagram for me. Here is the code so far:

```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='q02Nz _0TPg']").click()  #Clicks the Upload button
   typewrite('picture.png')           
   pyautogui.press('enter')            
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mXkkY KDuQp']").click()
```

Above code works for what I want it to do, clicks the upload button, typewrites the name of the image file and hits submit. Unfortunately, if the file that I need to upload is not in the default directory, I am not sure how to change directories. I have tried to typewrite the directory file in front of the name but that does not work. How do I change file directories through OS while uploading a file?

Comment: Just pass the absolute path?

Comment: You mean type in /home/desktop/myfolder/picture.png when typewriing the name of the picture? That method does not work.

Comment: You will have to be more specific. Do you get an error? Wrong output? Personally, I don't even know what `typewrite` is so it's a little hard to help...